# How to show a transparent app background in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-launcher, app-launcher

I am trying to make a simple launcher and I'm trying to show the app's background completely transparent or partially transparent. Could you guys help me out on how to do that?

Comment: Hi Nitin , could you please share the details  if you got the solution, I Am facing same issue. My launchers background is displaying as black

Comment: We honestly changed the UI because it was taking us hell lot of time. and its really hard to do it with compose just yet. but that was long time ago. May be you could find solution now.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible to do it, but not everything is on Compose side. There are a couple of things you need to do:

1- In your theme, you need to tell the system to show the wallpaper, make the **window** background transparent and tint all the bars transparent:

```
<style name="Theme.MyLauncher" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

2- Lastly, make your main surface transparent:

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    color = Color.Transparent
) {
    [...]
}
```

This should give you a nice and very transparent activity.

For bonus, check how to turn off the decor fitting system windows and you'll be able to draw anywhere in the window, giving you more flexibility. Cheers!

Comment: Let me try and get back. But already thanks for this

Comment: as of 2024, is there a way to do it only on Compose side ? and get rid of the xml theme completely ? thanks :)

Answer (score -3):

Yeah actually Android doesn't work that way. Your app is not open literally on top of the homescreen, pretty much like one activity is not opened above the previous one, it's just the animation and perception. However, if you want to create a launcher with a transparent background, there MAY be a way to get to know the current home screen background (although I doubt). Why not just set s default one of your own? Or maybe provide the user with a choice to customize it for your app?